# Redirect alias to main domain using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, alias

I'm attempting to redirect my client's domain alias (http://5sensescharity.co.uk) to their main domain http://5senses.co.uk.

I seem to have got this working using a response from another user's question, but can't get it working with every other possible url after the root. E.g 5sensescharity.co.uk/about/

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?5sensescharity\.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://5senses.co.uk/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?5sensescharity\.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://5senses.co.uk%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! This seems to do the exact same thing. When I visit 5sensescharity.co.uk/test/ it stays there rather than redirects to 5senses.co.uk/test/

Comment: Do you have a .htaccess inside `/test/` directory also??

Comment: There are no physical directories as it's a Wordpress site. /test/ doesn't actually exist, I was just using as an example. But no there are no other htaccess inside directories.

Comment: Hmm in that case make sure this rule is very first rule in WP .htaccess (just below `RewrteBase` line).

Comment: Perfect!! That was it, thanks Anubhava. My original rule works when placed above the WP rules in .htaccess. Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd rather try to use the Apache [RedirectPermanent](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectpermanent) or [RedirectTemp](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirecttemp) directives from mod_alias, because they're usually faster for Apache to process, e.g.:

```
RedirectPermanent / http://5senses.co.uk/
```

or

```
RedirectTemp / http://5senses.co.uk/
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but this just seems to create a redirect loop.

Comment: You did not mention that you host both domains on the same Apache instance (and <VirtualHost> configuration section). Just create a separate <VirtualHost> sections for www.5sensescharity.co.uk and 5sensescharity.co.uk in your Apache configuration and put the RedirectPermanent and/or RedirectTemp directives in those <VirtualHost> sections.